# Gatsby: "warn There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This can lead to unexpected behavior..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, warnings, gatsby

Building a Gatsby/React site with a folder structure that groups by feature. This is a fairly standard approach...

However if you name your folders using uppercase you will end up with some complaints in the console:

```
  warn There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
* css [path]/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--14-oneOf-1-1!/[path]/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss-3![path]/node_modules/sa
ss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--14-oneOf-1-3![path]/src/components/Layout/layout.scss 0
    Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
    [path]/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js??ref--14-oneOf-1-0!/[path]/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--14-oneOf-1-1!/[path]/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js??postcss-3![path]/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.j
s??ref--14-oneOf-1-3![path]/src/components/Layout/layout.scss
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rename your folders to be lowercase should fix your warnings:**

```
header/
  index.tsx
  stories.tsx
  style.scss
  test.tsx
footer/
  index.tsx
  stories.tsx
  style.scss
  index.test.ts
```